# Run a component in master job after all iterations of child job completes successfully

Tags: talend

I have a talend Parent job which runs 20 times a child job on Iterate Flow. I am trying to run another tjava after all the iterations of Child Job completes.

On connecting tjava with Child job for On Component ok, it is running for each iteration.

Is there a way to run after all iterations are done/complete.

Flow right now,

tDBInput --OnComponentOk--> tflowtoiterate --Iterate--> Child_Job(tRunJob) --OnComponentOk--> tjava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run tJava after all iterations are complete, you can connect like this tDbinput->onsubjobok->tJava.

Your flow and ieration connected to tDbinput will execute first, and then after all iterations, tJava will execute.